# electron-forge make failed due to 'openfolder' not supported on Apple Silicon devices

Tags: reactjs, typescript, macos, electron, electron-forge

I am using a MacBook Air M2 (Sonoma 14.0) with electron on version 27.0.3

I am trying to run the `electron-forge make` to make distributables for an Electron app. But when launching the command I get the follow error :

```bash
✔ Checking your system
✔ Loading configuration
✔ Resolving make targets
  › Making for the following targets: zip, dmg
✔ Running package command
  ✔ Preparing to package application
  ✔ Running packaging hooks
    ✔ Running generateAssets hook
    ✔ Running prePackage hook
      ✔ [plugin-webpack] Preparing native dependencies
      ✔ [plugin-webpack] Building webpack bundles
  ✔ Packaging application
    ✔ Packaging for x64 on darwin [3s]
  ✔ Running postPackage hook
✔ Running preMake hook
❯ Making distributables
  ✔ Making a zip distributable for darwin/x64 [11s]
  ✖ Making a dmg distributable for darwin/x64
    › Command failed: bless --folder /Volumes/ApplicationName --openfolder /Volumes/ApplicationName
      bless: The 'openfolder' is not supported on Apple Silicon devices.
◼ Running postMake hook


An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Command failed: bless --folder /Volumes/ApplicationName --openfolder /Volumes/ApplicationName
bless: The 'openfolder' is not supported on Apple Silicon devices.
at makeError (/Users/elerua/Code/CE-mainrepo/Frontend/node_modules/appdmg/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/elerua/Code/CE-mainrepo/Frontend/node_modules/appdmg/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I added in the `package.json` file multiple makers according to the documentation :

```json
"makers": [
    {
        "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
        "config": {
            "name": APPLICATION_NAME,
            "setupIcon": APPLICATION_ICON
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
        "config": {
            "name": APPLICATION_NAME
        },
        "platforms": [
            "darwin"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "@electron-forge/maker-dmg",
        "config": {
            "name": APPLICATION_NAME,
            "setupIcon": APPLICATION_ICON,
            "format": "ULFO"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
        "config": {
            "name": APPLICATION_NAME,
            "setupIcon": APPLICATION_ICON
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
        "config": {
            "name": APPLICATION_NAME,
            "setupIcon": APPLICATION_ICON
        }
    }
]
```

And I kept searching on Internet multiple way to unlock this issue but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution that wasn't able to be seen through the post. The default Node.js used on my computer was a v18.X.X built for x64 and not arm64. Once the proper Node.js version installed I achieved to pursue the `electron-forge make`.

### Tips

```bash
node -v || node --version # check version
nvm ls # list locally installed versions of node
nvm install 20.7.0 # install specific version of node
nvm alias default [NODE_VERSION_YOU_WANT_TO_USE] # set default version of node
nvm use [NODE_VERSION_YOU_WANT_TO_USE] # switch version of node
nvm install --lts # install latest LTS version of node (Long Term Support)
nvm install stable # install latest stable version of node
```